# alert when close browser and when close tab and click button back and forward

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to alert when close browser and when close tab and click button back and forward for logout admin inside php or else anywhere Or any other work Without using this command

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
```

or

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {
  return "Are you sure?"
});
```

Comment: why don't you want to use this command....

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return confirmEvent()">
```

javascript:

```
function confirmEvent(e) {
        return "do you really want to leave?";
}
```

Comment: Generally if not use this onbeforeunload ?